# print in single line in matlab command line

Tags: matlab

how to print to Command line in Matlab. which all output print statements will be in single line.

for example,

```
for i=1:4
   disp(i)     => or others print statement!
end
```

OUTPUT:
1234

Not:

1

2

3

4

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?refresh=true

Comment: this link is about print to text file not print in Command Window in Matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option using `fprintf`

```
for i=1:4
    fprintf('%d',i)
end
fprintf('\n') %//add a line break at the end
```

And if you want linebreaks at specific points use the `\n` escape sequence and also it allows you to some formatting such as spacing:

```
for i=1:12
    fprintf('%10d',i)
    if mod(i,3)==0
        fprintf('\n');
    end
end
```

Comment: +1 Good to know this doesn't produce a line break at each iteration

Comment: fprintf is for printing to text file not print in Command Window in Matlab.

Comment: @class1234 but it works just as well printing to the command line if you don't specify a file handle

Comment: I recommend using `fprintf(1,"%d",i);` - it makes it explicit that you are printing to "file id 1" (the console); it also makes your code compatible with other Matlab clones like Freemat. Leaving off the file ID is valid syntax in Matlab but one of those things that makes my skin crawl.